# Firebase: Manage User Session with Server without requiring user to sign-in again?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

We have a REST API (Python + Flask) that is exposed to external users through Google cloud functions. We also have a web application (React) that uses this API to show the results on the web. So we have two interfaces for our functionality: REST API and Web.

Now as per the new requirement we are implementing user Registration / Sign-in module (using Email & Password) on our website So that only registered / signed-in user can see the results on Web site.

We are planning to use Firebase.  Integrating Firebase Client SDK in our website was straight forward (a new login page added so that users can sign-in and once logged-in, they will remain logged in until the browser cookies are cleared).

We want to have similar authentication for our REST API’s users as well. The API user will first register himself on our website.  We’ll expose one more REST API `SignIn`  where he will pass registered email & password, which we will valid using Firebase `SignInWithPassword` (Firebase Admin SDK / Firebase REST API) and return the ID Token / Refresh Token. Now while using any other exposed API the user needs to send these tokens IDToken / RefreshToken , which we will validate  using `VerifiyIDToken()`.

The problem is that ID Tokens are short lived (1 hour expiration), and after that `VerifyIdToken` will fail. Now we don’t want API user to either call `SignIn` API again to get new ID Token / RefreshToken  or to visit our website to get any such token.

Is there is any way we can refresh API’s user ID Token without asking him to sign-in again?

Answer (score 2):

## Manage Tokens on Web Client

The website client code can call [User.getIdToken(forceRefresh?: *boolean*)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#get-idtoken):

> Returns the current token if it has not expired. Otherwise, this will refresh the token and return a new one.

This would need to be called each time a token is sent to the server.

---

Alternatively, user sessions may be managed via session cookies.

## [Manage Session Cookies](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies)

> Firebase Auth provides server-side session cookie management for traditional websites that rely on session cookies. This solution has several advantages over client-side short-lived ID tokens, which may require a redirect mechanism each time to update the session cookie on expiration:
>
> - Improved security via JWT-based session tokens that can only be generated using authorized service accounts.
> - Stateless session cookies that come with all the benefit of using JWTs for authentication. The session cookie has the same claims (including custom claims) as the ID token, making the same permissions checks enforceable on the session cookies.
> - Ability to create session cookies with custom expiration times ranging from 5 minutes to 2 weeks.
> - Flexibility to enforce cookie policies based on application requirements: domain, path, secure, `httpOnly`, etc.
> - Ability to revoke session cookies when token theft is suspected using the existing refresh token revocation API.
>
>   - Ability to detect session revocation on major account changes.